# AWS AppSync Subscriptions: Complex Authorization based on Object with in Updated Document

Tags: amazon-web-services, subscription, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

The object that will be changed by a mutation contains a `permissions` array that contains `user` objects that consist of a `userId` and a `write` permission boolean. If a user's `userId` is present in the list, the user has read permission on the object. If `write` is set to true, the user also has write permission.

This makes modifying the object easier from a mutation perspective, but it makes handling subscriptions much more difficult, since I don't have access to the object being updated at subscription creation. Thus, I am unable to ensure that user's will only get updates to the object if they have the appropriate permissions.

I don't think it makes a difference (since I can't handle this on the client-side securely), but I'm building a React web client.

Is there any feasible way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to setup a server-side job which subscribes to all new mutations. This server-side listener would receive every new mutation, look into the permissions list, and publish to the authorized user using a None datasource resolver. The users will only be allowed to subscribe to a subscription with their user id.

The schema would look something like this:

```
type Object {
  permissions: [User]
  //.. Other fields
}

type User {
  userId: ID!
  write: Boolean
}

// The server listener will populate this
type PublishPayload {
  userId: ID!
  objectToPublish: Object
}

type Mutation {
  // The original mutation
  updateObject(): Object

  // The server-side listener will use this to publish. Attach a None Resolver to it.
  publishToUser(userId: ID!): PublishPayload
}

type Subscription {
  // This subscription is used by the server to listen to all updateObject mutations
  serverSubscription(): Object
  @aws_subscribe(mutations:["updateObject"])

  // This subscription is used by the users. 
  // You would add a resolver to it that fails authorization if they try to subscribe to a different user.
  userSubscription(userId: ID!): PublishPayload
  @aws_subscribe(mutations:["publishToUser"])

//.. More schema
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's an excellent idea. I will give it a try tonight and let you know how it goes. I can't help but feel that, in general, I'm applying a lot of "workarounds" in order to use AppSync as a SaaS provider, but I suppose for the price point there's no beating it. I just hope that it proves to be maintainable going forward.

Comment: Wouldn't the server-side listener in this case need to be an EC2 instance or container, since Lambda is short-lived?